# AWS S3 utilizing for website static images

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

We currently are moving our website to EC2 utilizing OpsWorks. Right now we reference all media files for the site with relative URL's in the coding... "/images/image1.jpg" and so on. Is there a way to alias the /images directory in our coding to utilize an S3 bucket? What we'd like to do is get big sized images out onto S3 so it's not stored withe each of our S3 instances.

I know we can create an alias DNS entry for the bucket itself, but then we'd have to reference that full URL inside of our coding. For instance, http://images.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com. We'd rather keep the URL referencing in the coding relative and an absolute path.

We are utilizing AWS Linux for the PHP/Apache front end EC2 instances.

Comment: You can either write your own handler to use the S3 CLI at application level and route all requests to an S3 bucket, you can use Cloudfront (an AWS CDN) to front the S3 bucket, and point a DNS entry to it, then use `images.yoursite.com/images/` as an alias for it, or you can use something like `s3fuse` (never found it that great myself) to create a mount on your EC2 instance to S3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Apache then you could proxy all the /images URL's using Apache's built-in proxy support. You would want to add something like this to your Apache configuration:

```
ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /images/ http://images.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/
```

This actually creates a reverse proxy.  When the Apache server sees a request that matches /images/ then it will reach out to the S3 URL to fetch the object and return it back to the client.

Comment: the OP may not realize a subtle point about this- it sends all traffic through your server, so you have more data (and more hits) on the server. But it's about the only way if you don't want to reference a subdomain.

Comment: Our idea is really to have a single point for our bigger image files rather than having them stored locally in the /images directory on each of our EC2 instance. Utilizing OpsWorks, we can have a few instances ready on load waiting and would have to deploy the ~1GB zip file for code. If we can pull out those images to an S3 bucket, that zip file for deployment would be about 200MB and faster to deploy.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something then my suggestion of proxying the /images/ requests (or some other URL path) to S3 would work perfectly well in this case.  The images would reside on S3, you could refer to them in your site as '/images/big_image.jpg', and the proxy statement would cause the image to be fetched from S3. As tedder42 pointed out, this approach would cause all traffic to flow through the OpsWorks instances, but given your description that doesn't sound like a big deal.

Comment: Correct. I am going to go this route and test it out.

Comment: The Apache ProxyPass worked as planned for this. I'm returning to this question, because now I need to get that apache proxy configuration into the apache config automatically via the chef recipes for OpsWorks. Has anyone done templating or configuration to 'adjust' the apache configuration for the website?

Comment: As that's a completely new question I'd recommend submitting it as a new question and not a followup comment to this one.  The only people likely to see what you asked are those of us who already posted here (and so we received notifications of your comment), and personally I have no experience at all with Chef. Actually, it sounds like the sort of question that's likely already been asked and answered on StackOverflow so I'd suggest searching for similar questions and submit a new question only if no similar one is found.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up apache to return redirects to the URLs of the images stored in S3.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit?